# saving Map<int, Class<>> to Internal Memory in Android

Tags: android, intentservice

this is probably a simple question but i cant find the answer.
i have a bunch of IntentServices which parses web service and saves data to local DB. and i invoke them at runtime based on ID provided like this:

```
private Map<Integer, Pair> serviceMap;

void initService(int ID){
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, serviceMap.get(ID).intentServiceClass);
        startService(intent);
}

private class Pair{
    private Class<? extends IntentService> intentServiceClass;
    private int dataVersion; 
}
```

dataVersion in Pair class is the "version" of data available in local DB.
intentServiceClass refers to a IntentService which will make a call to server only if newer "version" of data available on server.

now i want to save this serviceMap as dataVersion is used to avoid unnecessary server calls.

so any suggetions ?

i made Pair class Parceble as to save it to internal memory but i don't know how to deal with "Class" and Parceble.

Answer (score 0):

Just save full class name (i.e. `com.example.myapp.MyClass`) and then just get reference to `Class` object using `Class.forName()` method (`Class.forName("com.example.myapp.MyClass")` in our case).

Note, that you **should not** try to save `Parcelable` objects in persistent storage (as suggested by documentation) "as is", since the way those objects are "deserialized" (unmarshalled, to be more precise) may differs between platforms

Comment: ok, thats right cant use parcelable/serializable to save in persistent storage. so i think i only have sqlite option right?

Comment: @Ankit SQLite **is** persistent storage :) That's what I meant